# Laravel updateOrCreate ignores 1 field

Tags: laravel

I have the following updateOrCreate:

```
protected $fillable = ['type', 'token', 'expires_on'];

$access = Ebaytoken::updateOrCreate(
   ['type' => 'access_token'],
   ['token' => $request->access_token, 'expires_on' => $request->access_token_expires_on]
);
```

However it gives this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'type', table 'toolkit.dbo._ebaytokens'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (SQL: insert into [_ebaytokens] ([token], [expires_on], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (access token goes here, 2020-03-09 09:01:02, 2021-07-12 14:18:31.031, 2021-07-12 14:18:31.031))
```

It's ignoring the `type` column in my query.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: did you by any chance override the constructor of that model? can you do this and see if it includes your 'type' field: `dump((new Ebaytoken(['type' => 'blah']))->toArray())`

Comment: Yes! Thats a great shout.  Does this mess with the functionality? How do I get around this?

Comment: yea you can not remove the functionality of that constructor, as that is often how a new instance is created with attributes, by the constructor ... it must take an array of attributes and 'fill' them on the instance ... so if you are going to override that you still need to take the first arg as the attributes array and then call `parent::__construct($attributes)` to make sure that functionality is there ... and the constructor calls some other methods too in there so the parent constructor needs to be called ... though i would just not override the constructor at all

Comment: @Lee try to 100% avoid modifying core laravel classes' constructors... there are most of the time other approaches to modify a class. Read the documentation a little bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined your own constructor on your model which is not its default constructor it gets from the `Model` class. The constructor on `Model` takes the attributes as an array and fills them on the instance. This way you can create a new instance of a Model with attributes. This is the important part of that constructor:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    ...

    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

Without that you wouldn't be able to create a new Model instance with attributes filled.

This is what `updateOrCreate` is doing:

```
public function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    return tap($this->firstOrNew($attributes), function ($instance) use ($values) {
        $instance->fill($values)->save();
    });
}
```

It is retrieving by the attributes or creating a new instance with the attributes (first argument). Eventually down those method calls you get to `Model::newInstance` which is doing this:

```
$model = new static((array) $attributes);
```

So without that constructor it can't create that new instance of the Model with those attributes, which in this case because of calling `updateOrCreate` is the first array you pass to `updateOrCreate`. It can fill the instance with the second array though as that is just a call to `fill` on the Model instance.

I would suggest to not override the constructor on a Model but if you really need to you could show what you are trying to do and perhaps you could get some advice or ideas on how to go about it.